# jqGrid colModel parameters inside php array

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, json, jqgrid

I'm working with a project that uses jqGrid in the most recent version.
The thing is that this project is PHP(5.6) and uses JSON to "translate/talk" to jqGrid framework, and colModel parameters are all inside PHP arrays.
**It works flawlessly but i'm unable to trigger dataInit of colModel "criacao" using the actual project's code**.
Thx for your time!

```
public function laudos($section)
    {
        $table = 'laudos';
        $fields = array('id','laudo','nome_fantasia','cliente','cadastro_id','email','senha','exame','descricao','criacao','exclusao','arquivo');
        $tabela = array(
            'colNames' => array('ID','Laudo','Clínica','Nome','Cadastro','Email','Senha','Exame','Descrição','Criação','Exclusão','Arquivo'),
            'colModel' => array(
                array('name'=>'id','hidden'=>true,'search'=>true,'key'=>true),
                array('name'=>'laudo','index'=>'laudo','width'=>70,'align'=>'center','search'=>true,'editable'=>true,'editrules'=>array('required'=>true),'sorttype'=>'integer','searchoptions'=>array('sopt'=>'[eq,cn]', 'clearSearch'=>false)),
                array('name'=>'nome_fantasia','search'=>true,'width'=>170,'align'=>'center','editable'=>false,'sorttype'=>'text','searchoptions'=>array('sopt'=>'[eq,cn]','clearSearch'=>false),'editrules'=>array('required'=>true)),
                array('name'=>'cliente','search'=>true,'width'=>170,'align'=>'center','editable'=>false,'sorttype'=>'text','searchoptions'=>array('sopt'=>'[eq,cn]','clearSearch'=>false),'editrules'=>array('required'=>true),),
                array('name'=>'cadastro_id','search'=>true,'hidden'=>true,
                    'editable'=>true,'edittype'=>'text','searchoptions'=>array('sopt'=>'[eq,cn]','clearSearch'=>false),'editrules'=>array('edithidden'=>true,'required'=>true),
                    'editoptions'=>array('dataInit'=>'[]')),
                array('name'=>'email','search'=>true,'hidden'=>true,'editable'=>true,'sorttype'=>'email','searchoptions'=>array('sopt'=>'[eq,cn]','clearSearch'=>false),'editrules'=>array('edithidden'=>true)),
                array('name'=>'senha','search'=>true,'hidden'=>true,'editable'=>true,'editrules'=>array('edithidden'=>true)),
                array('name'=>'exame','search'=>true,'width'=>50,'align'=>'center','editable'=>true,'sorttype'=>'text','searchoptions'=>array('sopt'=>'[eq,cn]','clearSearch'=>false),'formatter'=>'select','edittype'=>'select',
                    'editoptions'=>array('value'=>array('Biópsia'=>'Biópsia','Necrópsia'=>'Necrópsia','Citologia'=>'Citologia'))
                ),
                array('name'=>'descricao','search'=>true,'width'=>200,'align'=>'center','editable'=>true,'sorttype'=>'text','searchoptions'=>array('sopt'=>'[eq,cn]','clearSearch'=>false)),
                array('name'=>'criacao','search'=>true,'width'=>70,'formatter'=>'date','fixed'=>true,'resizable'=>false,'align'=>'center','sorttype'=>'date','searchoptions'=>array('sopt'=>'[eq,cn]','clearSearch'=>false), 'editoptions'=>array('dataInit'=>'function (elem) { $(elem).datepicker();')),
                array('name'=>'exclusao','search'=>true,'width'=>70,'formatter'=>'date','sorttype'=>'date','fixed'=>true,'resizable'=>false,'editable'=>true,'searchoptions'=>array('sopt'=>'[eq,cn]','clearSearch'=>false),'align'=>'center'),
                array('name'=>'arquivo','search'=>false,'width'=>60,'formatter'=>'arquivo','classes'=>'tabela_laudo_arquivo','editable'=>true,'searchoptions'=>array('sopt'=>false,'clearSearch'=>false))
            ),
            'sortname' => 'id',
            'caption' => 'Registros de Laudos Cadastrados',
            );
```

**UPDATE:**
Using jQGrid $.extend, it was possible to set colModel attributes using php and a base java script with all jQGrid settings, properties and events.

**EXAMPLE:**

```
var p = $("#tabela-laudos").jqGrid("getGridParam");
        //=================================================
        p.colModel[p.iColByName.laudo] = $.extend(true,
            {},
            p.colModel[p.iColByName.laudo], //NEW VALUES BELOW
            {
                editoptions:
                {
                    placeholder: "Ex.: 17777"
                },
            }
        );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using jQGrid $.extend, it is possible to set colModel attributes settings, properties and events of colModel's even after inital settings loaded.

**EXAMPLE:**

```
var p = $("#tabela-laudos").jqGrid("getGridParam");
        //=================================================
        p.colModel[p.iColByName.laudo] = $.extend(true,
            {},
            p.colModel[p.iColByName.laudo], //NEW VALUES BELOW
            {
                editoptions:
                {
                    placeholder: "Ex.: 17777"
                },
            }
        );
```