# jqGrid dataInit doesn't trigger

Tags: php, jquery, json, jqgrid

I'm working with a project that uses jqGrid in the most recent version.

The thing is that this project is PHP(5.6) and uses JSON to "translate/talk" to jqGrid framework, and colModel parameters are all inside PHP arrays. **It works flawlessly** but i'm **unable to trigger dataInit of colModel "criacao" using the actual project's code**.

```
public function laudos($section)
    {
        $table = 'laudos';
        $fields = array('id','laudo','nome_fantasia','cliente','cadastro_id','email','senha','exame','descricao','criacao','exclusao','arquivo');
        $tabela = array(
            'colNames' => array('ID','Laudo','Clínica','Nome','Cadastro','Email','Senha','Exame','Descrição','Criação','Exclusão','Arquivo'),
            'colModel' => array(
                array('name'=>'id','hidden'=>true,'search'=>true,'key'=>true),
                array('name'=>'laudo','index'=>'laudo','width'=>70,'align'=>'center','search'=>true,'editable'=>true,'editrules'=>array('required'=>true),'sorttype'=>'integer','searchoptions'=>array('sopt'=>'[eq,cn]', 'clearSearch'=>false)),
                array('name'=>'nome_fantasia','search'=>true,'width'=>170,'align'=>'center','editable'=>false,'sorttype'=>'text','searchoptions'=>array('sopt'=>'[eq,cn]','clearSearch'=>false),'editrules'=>array('required'=>true)),
                array('name'=>'cliente','search'=>true,'width'=>170,'align'=>'center','editable'=>false,'sorttype'=>'text','searchoptions'=>array('sopt'=>'[eq,cn]','clearSearch'=>false),'editrules'=>array('required'=>true),),
                array('name'=>'cadastro_id','search'=>true,'hidden'=>true,
                    'editable'=>true,'edittype'=>'text','searchoptions'=>array('sopt'=>'[eq,cn]','clearSearch'=>false),'editrules'=>array('edithidden'=>true,'required'=>true),
                    'editoptions'=>array('dataInit'=>'[]')),
                array('name'=>'email','search'=>true,'hidden'=>true,'editable'=>true,'sorttype'=>'email','searchoptions'=>array('sopt'=>'[eq,cn]','clearSearch'=>false),'editrules'=>array('edithidden'=>true)),
                array('name'=>'senha','search'=>true,'hidden'=>true,'editable'=>true,'editrules'=>array('edithidden'=>true)),
                array('name'=>'exame','search'=>true,'width'=>50,'align'=>'center','editable'=>true,'sorttype'=>'text','searchoptions'=>array('sopt'=>'[eq,cn]','clearSearch'=>false),'formatter'=>'select','edittype'=>'select',
                    'editoptions'=>array('value'=>array('Biópsia'=>'Biópsia','Necrópsia'=>'Necrópsia','Citologia'=>'Citologia'))
                ),
                array('name'=>'descricao','search'=>true,'width'=>200,'align'=>'center','editable'=>true,'sorttype'=>'text','searchoptions'=>array('sopt'=>'[eq,cn]','clearSearch'=>false)),
                array('name'=>'criacao','search'=>true,'width'=>70,'formatter'=>'date','fixed'=>true,'resizable'=>false,'align'=>'center','sorttype'=>'date','searchoptions'=>array('sopt'=>'[eq,cn]','clearSearch'=>false), 'editoptions'=>array('dataInit'=>'function (elem) { $(elem).datepicker();')),
                array('name'=>'exclusao','search'=>true,'width'=>70,'formatter'=>'date','sorttype'=>'date','fixed'=>true,'resizable'=>false,'editable'=>true,'searchoptions'=>array('sopt'=>'[eq,cn]','clearSearch'=>false),'align'=>'center'),
                array('name'=>'arquivo','search'=>false,'width'=>60,'formatter'=>'arquivo','classes'=>'tabela_laudo_arquivo','editable'=>true,'searchoptions'=>array('sopt'=>false,'clearSearch'=>false))
            ),
            'sortname' => 'id',
            'caption' => 'Registros de Laudos Cadastrados',
            );
```

This is the PHP function that returns a responce to jqgrid framework:

```
private function tabelas($table, $fields, $where = '1 = 1')
    {
        $page  = isset($_REQUEST['page']) ? $_REQUEST['page'] : 1; // get the requested page
        $limit = isset($_REQUEST['rows']) ? $_REQUEST['rows'] : 99999; // get how many rows we want to have into the grid
        $sidx  = isset($_REQUEST['sidx']) ? $_REQUEST['sidx'] : 'id'; // get index row - i.e. user click to sort
        $sord  = isset($_REQUEST['sord']) ? $_REQUEST['sord'] : 'desc'; // get the direction

        if(!$sidx) $sidx =1;

        $count = $this->db->get_var("SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM $table WHERE $where");
        if($count > 0)
        {
            $total_pages = ceil($count/$limit);
        }
        else
        {
            $total_pages = 0;
        }

        if ($page > $total_pages) $page = $total_pages;
        $start = $limit * $page - $limit; // do not put $limit*($page - 1)      
        $sql = "SELECT " . implode(',',$fields) . " FROM $table WHERE $where ORDER BY $sidx $sord LIMIT $start, $limit";
        $result = $this->db->get_results($sql);
        $responce->page = $page;
        $responce->total = $total_pages;
        $responce->records = $count;
        $i = 0;
        foreach($result as $row)
        {
            $responce->rows[$i]['id'] = $row->id;
            foreach($fields as $field)
            {
                $responce->rows[$i]['cell'][] = $row->$field;
            }
            $i++;
        }
        return $responce;

    }
```

Comment: jqGrid is written in **JavaScript**. Please send the resulting JavaScript code, which produces your PHP code.

Comment: Oleg, i know that but this is what is driving me crazy! I don't know how to see the resulting code since colModel is set via a PHP file and this PHP file returns a $responce  variable encoded in JSON format.

Comment: You need just use context menu in the web browser to see the source code of the page. Th code will include full HTML and JavaScript code.

Comment: Yep, i already did it but since properties are sent by PHP the source code are completely clean from the jqgrid output. It only fiils the tables on-the-fly. :/

Comment: I just need to understand how to write correctly a js function code inside dataInit inside a php array in a way that jqgrid could understand.

Comment: Oleg sorry for the headache. Thank you for any help in advance. I spent more than A MONTH working on this before come here ask.

Comment: It's unclear *where* you use `laudos` function. The code `'dataInit'=>'function (elem) { $(elem).datepicker();'` is wrong, because you assign **string** instead of function. You should make **more changes** in your code in the way how you fill `colModel`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jqGrid colModel parameters inside php array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40364247/jqgrid-colmodel-parameters-inside-php-array)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using $.extend in my jQGrid script did the job.
Question already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40364247/jqgrid-colmodel-parameters-inside-php-array).